# How to use component variable in direct input mode

Tags: rules

I'm trying to use a component variable in direct input mode, but as far as I know there's no token for variables. Is this a yet-to-implement feature of Rules, or is there any workarounds?

For example if you want to use Rules programmatically, you could call `rules_invoke_component($component_name, $variable1, ...)` to pass the variables to the component and execute it. It would be pretty nice to use the value of those variables in the body of an e-mail for example, but it's not possible, because AFAIK you can't use variables in direct input mode.

Comment: More info on what you're trying to accomplish with Rules?

Comment: @Jay: I've added an example use case.